# Multiple IPs on Host Accessible from VM

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, virtualization

I use [Windows XP Mode](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx) to test sites for IE6 compatibility. I run several sites in my host machine's IIS service, each on a different local IP (127.0.1.0, 127.2.1.3, etc.), which is important because I need multiple local sites to be able to run in https simultaneously.

Since IE6 runs in a virtual instance of Windows XP, I can only hit one IP on the hose machine - its network address (192.168.x.x). Is there any way to "tunnel" or route IPs from the virtual instance to the host OS, such that if I pointed a virtual web browser to 127.1.1.3, it would hit the IIS site on the host machine which is bound to 127.1.1.3?

Thanks for any help!

**Edit:** I finally figured it out, and can't figure out why it took me so long to realize.

Solution: Setup a proxy server on the host OS. Point the virtual IE6 to the host proxy server. All requests will go through the proxy server and hit the various IPs/sites as if the virtual application were running on the host OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup a proxy server on the host OS. Point the virtual IE6 to the host proxy server. All requests will go through the proxy server and hit the various IPs/sites as if the virtual application were running on the host OS.

Answer (score 0):

well as 127. is bound to loopback, and that by default means only localhost, so if it is running in a vm it is never going to leave the vm.

Can you possible just run evey instance on a different port.  ue 127.0.1.1 would now listen on 192.168.x.x:8080 and 127.2.1.3 listens on post 8081.  SSL would work fine on all them, although you would need to test with the port number in place